# Powershell open dropdown menu / click a link

Tags: html, windows, powershell

I´m having a little problem with Poershell.

I´d like the click on a link to get further information. But the problem is, the link is in a dropdown menu.

Normally, I would use something like this

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $fasle
$link = $ie.Navigate('url')
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')| 
    where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'my match'}

$link.click()
```

The dropdown menu looks kinda like this:

```
<td>

  <select class="form" name="request" onchange="form.change();">

        <option value="someValue" >Name</option>
        <option value="someValue2" >MyLink</option>
```

e.g. I´d  like to click on "**MyLink**".

Thanks in advance

Comment: In first code part you are looking for `a` element, but html is missing all `a` elements

Comment: This is just an example. I´m aware of it

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to fully load in IE?

Comment: Yes. I´ve alerady added While ($ie.Busy) {
Sleep 2
}

Or what do you mean ?  :)

Comment: You should be checking IE's `ReadyState`.  `$ie.ReadyState -eq 4` will tell you if the document is ready.